# Найдите и исправьте ошибку в программе для нахождения факториала

Tags: javascript, функции

Всем привет, коллеги! У меня есть вот такая задачка, бьюсь над ней со вчерашнего дня, но никак не могу найти ошибку. Условие такое:
Найдите и исправьте ошибку в программе для нахождения факториала.

И вот код

```
var counter = prompt("Введите число");
var factorial = 1;

document.write("Факториал числа: " + counter + "! = ");

do {

     if (counter == 0) {
                factorial = 1;
                break;
     }

     factorial = factorial / counter;
     counter = counter + 1;
}
while (counter > 0);

document.write(factorial);
```

В подсказках написано, что что-то не так с самой переменной factorial, но я ничего не вижу. Пробовала разные варианты, в том числе писать factorial = factorial * counter; вместо factorial = factorial / counter;, но нет, тут явно что-то другое. Речь идет о сайте, с автоматической проверкой задачек, поэтому думаю, что тут что-то небольшое надо исправить, и не нужно переписывать все полностью. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Хм, а вы вообще знаете что такое факториал?

Comment: Боюсь, вам придется переписать все. Факториал это умножение цифр от 1 до n, где n это ваш counter. условие выхода из цикла, в текущем виде, никогда не сработает. Это бесконечный цикл, т.к. counter постоянно увеличивается, а цикл работает до тех пор, пока counter больше нуля - т.е.всегда. Ну и не плохо было бы counter сразу преобразовать к числу, т.к. prompt возвращает строку

Comment: И еще есть сомнения, что автоматическая проверка благосклонно относится к `document.write()`

Comment: SwaD, а вы бы могли пожалуйста написать, что конкретно нужно убрать? Делала разные манипуляции со строкой while (counter > 0);- пока ничего не помогает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ребят, решение верное оказалось следующим:

```
    var counter = prompt("Enter the number");
    var factorial = 1;
    
    document.write("Factorial of a number: " + counter + "! = ");
    
    do {
        if (counter == 0) {
            factorial = 1;
            break;
        }
    
        factorial = factorial * counter;
        counter = counter - 1;
    } while (counter > 0);

document.write(factorial);
```

Решила поделиться. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Было бы красиво от вас, если вы бы явно написали, где разница, в которой команде, и почему она была плохой. Иначе разделяю вашу радость. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Способ с циклом:

```
let counter = prompt("Введите число");
function factorial(n) {
    let result = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      result *= i;
    }
    console.log("Факториал числа: " + counter + "! = " + result);
}
factorial(counter)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за вариант, но система его не принимает :( Видимо нужно именно внести исправления в текущий код, но я уже что только не пробовала :(